# Django: change the value of a field for all objects in a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model `MyModel` with a boolean field `active`

Elsewhere, I am retrieving a queryset:

```
qs = MyModel.Objects.filter(....)
```

how can I set `active=False` for all objects in this `qs`?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can update all the records in the queryset with

```
qs.update(active=False)
```

Please refer to the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) for more info

Comment: It should be noted that qs.update() will *not* call the model's save function.  Sure, this is obvious; however, for developers that rely on code to execute during save, they will need to be aware of this!

Answer (score 8):

And of course you can pass many arguments to update e.g.:

```
qs.update(active=False, is_deleted=True, date_finished=timezone.now())
```

Edit:
Additionally. This simple qs.update(...) won't work on sliced querysets. For example if you have:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)[:10]
user.update(is_active=False)  # This will throw error
```

in that kind of situation, since Django 2.2, you can use [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) method like:

```
users_to_update = list(User.objects.filter(is_active=True)[:10])
for i in range(10):
    users_to_update.is_active = False

User.objects.bulk_update(users_to_update, ["is_active"])
```

This will be generally done in one query not in 10 separate queries. I've faced that kind of requirements in one of my project. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: users_to_update[i].is_active = False   - otherwise, very helpful, thank you. :)